# HQL - fetch all the rows of table A and join on condition with table B

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have an EVENT table. Every Event can have one or more EventDates :

```
class Event{
    private String eventId;
    private Set<EventDates> dates;
}

class EventDates {
    private String dateId;
    private Integer startingDate;
    private Integer endingDate;
}
```

An Event does not necessarily have an EventDates

I want to select **all** the events, and only join the EventDates whose starting date is superior to datetime.

Say for example :

In the Table Event :

```
eventId 

    1   

    2   

    3

    4
```

In the Table EventDates :

```
dateId ║ startingDate ║ endingDate ║ eventId

    1 ║     yesterday ║  nextWeek ║ '1'

    2 ║     today     ║  nextWeek ║ '2'

    3 ║     tomorrow  ║  nextWeek ║ '3'
```

The dates are actually in timestamp, to avoid convertion, I used common words.

Now, I want to select ***all*** the events, but only join the eventsDates whose startingDate is superior to today.

I used this query :

```
SELECT E from EVENT E 
LEFT JOIN FETCH E.dates D 
WHERE ( D IS NULL OR D.startingDate > 'today')
```

I get the events 3 & 4 with their associated eventDates.

What I wanted to have : All the events : 1, 2, 3 and 4. With only the associated eventsDates of 3 & 4. ( As the associated eventDates of 1 & 2 do not meet the condition )

Thank you.

Comment: In the end it all comes down to SQL. So what SQL do you think would fulfill your goal?

Comment: What do you mean ? I have a mySql Databse

Comment: I am suggesting you to write **SQL query** that would fulfill your goal. Based on that we can think of corresponding HQL.